# How to rotate the cube I click instead of all cubes rotating at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

So i am instantiating cubes and i want to rotate a single cube which i click, however when i click on the cube, all instantiated cubes rotate at the same time, I keep trying with boolean but no success. Any help would be appreciated. UNITY 2D

```
{
    public int rotationDirection = -1; //-1 for clockwise
    public int rotationStep = 5; //Should be less than 90

    public bool noRotation;

    // public GameObject cubeBox;
    private Vector3 currentRotation, targetRotation;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

            if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "colourBox" && noRotation == false)
            {
                Debug.Log("object clicked: " + hit.collider.tag);
                
                RotateCube(); 
            }
        }
    }
    void RotateCube()
    {
        currentRotation = gameObject.transform.eulerAngles;
        targetRotation.z = (currentRotation.z + (90 * rotationDirection));
        StartCoroutine(objectRotationAnimation());
    }

    IEnumerator objectRotationAnimation()
    {
        currentRotation.z += (rotationStep * rotationDirection);
        gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = currentRotation;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);

        if (((int)currentRotation.z > (int)targetRotation.z && rotationDirection < 0))
        {
            StartCoroutine(objectRotationAnimation());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition check if a cube is clicked, but it need check if the current cube is clicked. I don't know unity, but maybe `if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "colourBox" && hit.collider.attachedRigidbody == this && noRotation == false)`.

Comment: I changed the ray cast into OnMouseDown and it solved the problem. But i still want to know what would be the solution if I used the code above!`private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        RotateCube();
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this script is present on all cubes.

The problem is that when you click with your mouse **every single cube** will create its own instance of a raycast. After that **every cube** will check if the `hit.collider` is not `null`, if its tag is `colourBox` and if `noRotation` equals `false`.

You in fact don't check anywhere what cube you just clicked on. You can simply add this check by comparing the instance ID of the gameobject the raycast collided with and the instance ID of the gameobject where the script runs.

```
if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "colourBox" && noRotation == false)
{
    // Check if the cube that was clicked was this cube
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetInstanceID() == gameObject.GetInstanceID())
    {
        Debug.Log("object clicked: " + hit.collider.tag);

        RotateCube();
    }
}
```

This way every cube will compare its instance ID with the instance ID of the clicked object. Only the clicked object will return `true` in this `if` statement and thus runs the `RotateCube` method.

Answer (score 1):

Used this instead of RayCastHit2D ....Deleted everything inside Update and created a new void.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        RotateCube();
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.